# DynamoDB error insert Maping

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying insert in AWS DynamoDB, I get insert the register but I get error in Java (Eclipse) When I Insert, but repeat, I see table in DynamoDB my insert.

I get error ->

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: Aricle[ID_TABLE]: null or empty value for primary key
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.unconvert(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:171)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$ValueUpdate.apply(DynamoDBMapper.java:1440)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(DynamoDBMapper.java:746)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:622)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.save(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:113)
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.core.DynamoDBTemplate.save(DynamoDBTemplate.java:136)
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.SimpleDynamoDBCrudRepository.save(SimpleDynamoDBCrudRepository.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

My class Java

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "ARTICLE")
public class Article{

    @Id
    private String ID_TABLE;

    private String description;

public Article() {
    }

public Article(String description) {
     this.description=description;
    }

@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "ID_TABLE")
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public String getID_TABLE() {
        return ID_TABLE;
    }

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

I upload this with null or empty value for primary key, BUT I get `@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey` ...

I send with Angular the object Article with :

```
export class Article{
    id: string;
    description: string;
}

  let newParam: Article= {
            id: '', 
            description: 'chair' 
    };
```

Then I now understand that how I send '' ,  `@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey` Doesn't run, Because I tried with

```
let newParam: Article= {
                id: null,
```

And I get error null

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: null (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 407; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)
```

Then If I have send a Object to SpringBoot from Angular, AND this object the Angular need declarate id and The Object from Springboot gets this object, how do I generated key ?

Edit with new data.

I get Object

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/addParam", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public MyMessage addParam(@RequestBody Article article) {
         try {
            pgRepository.save(article);
            result = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

repository:

```
public interface Article Repository extends CrudRepository<Article , String> {
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you used to parse and save the object?

Answer (score 0):

Once you added the @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey annotation which a hash key or range key property as being auto-generated.The Object Persistence Model will generate a random UUID when saving these attributes. Only String properties can be marked as auto-generated keys.

> This key will be null till until you call the save method to save it
>   in the database. When you call the save then API will generate a UUID
>   and save in the database also set the same into your object.

A code snip will be:

```
public static void saveItem() {
   Article obj = new Article();
   obj.setDescription("abc123");
   // ID_TABLE field is null at this point      
   DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);
   mapper.save(obj);
   // ID_TABLE field will have a value at this point 
   System.out.println("Object was saved with id " + obj.getID_TABLE());
```

}

I hope this helps.

Comment: But I send value "id" from Angular.

Comment: you no need to send that value from yourself as you are expecting that from database. just remove that from your request.

Comment: send only this: let newParam: Article= {
            description: 'chair' 
    };

Comment: I can't remove from my request because I need this input en Angular5

Comment: Then Set it to null.

Comment: DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient); dynamoDBclient ? my object Article ?

Comment: It's client object which have database connection. refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.html

Comment: null or empty value for primary key

Comment: Should be null, not empty.both have different meanings.

Comment: Hi  Shivang Agarwal, I send var id = null from Angular, then SpringBoot receive this object with id= null, I use extends CRUD for save this object, You use mapper. If I send null or '' My CRUD INSERT the object BUT I get error. thanks.

Comment: Attached your spring code here. using to save the object.

Comment: I found solution I need  setID_TABLE() XD